the sum of vectors belonging to any proper subset of vectors from the center of regular polygon
There is the following problem:  Consider the regular $1987$-gon $A_1, A_2,..., A_{1987}$ with center O.      Show that the sum of vectors belonging to any proper subset of
$M =\{OA_j | j = 1, 2, . . . , 1987\}$ is nonzero.
There are some observations:

If some proper subset has sum equal to zero that its complement also has this property because the sum of all vectors is equal to zero. So there are subsets with even and odd number of elements with sum equal to zero.
May be the property that $1987$ is prime number might be useful.

Update: I found (more exactly, Copilot founds) the following paper: ON VANISHING SUMS OF DISTINCT ROOTS OF UNITY. As there is written in the abstract:"We show that for any integers $n ≥ 2$ and $0 ≤ k ≤ n$, one may find $k$ distinct $nth$
roots of unity whose sum is $0$ if and only if both $k$ and $n − k$ are expressible as
linear combinations of prime factors of $n$ with nonnegative coefficients". So this fact solves the problem because 1987 is prime number. But may be there are other solutions?

Is $O$ defined to be the centroid of the $1987$-gon?

@Angae: Yes, O is the centroid.

How familiar are you with manipulating complex numbers as vectors?

The primality of $1987$ is crucial. We identify the vertices with the complex numbers $e^{2\pi ik/1987}$, $k=0,1,\dotsc,1986$. They are the roots of the polynomial $x^{1987}-1=0$. This polynomial factors over the integers as
$$
(x-1)(x^{1986}+x^{1985}+\dotsb+x+1)
$$
The factor of degree $1986$ is irreducible over the integers (this is where the primality of $1987$ comes in). The field obtained from the rationals by adjoining a root $\zeta$ of this factor is a vector space over the rationals of dimension $1986$, and any $1986$ of the roots of $x^{1987}-1$ can be taken as a basis for this vector space. That means they are linearly independent over the rationals, so no sum (indeed, no nontrivial linear combination) of them can be zero.
